# Use grep to parse data

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I'm trying to get specific data from the smartctl command. I want to get the total power_on_hours, but I don't want all the filler. I just want the straight hours. This is the command I've come up with now:

```
smartctl -A /dev/sda | grep Power_On_Hours
```

My output is then something similar to:

```
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
```

I want the last number on the line. I figure that I can probably somehow read to the end of the file and count back to the first space or search until the hyphen and read until the end of the file. I just don't know how I would do that. My experience with grep is way too low to know how to approach this. My goal is to have the output be something like:

```
27
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can/want to use `awk` it is easy to grab the last field with `awk '{print $NF}'`. E.g., building on what you already have:

```
smartctl -A /dev/sda | grep Power_On_Hours | awk '{print $NF}'
```

`NF` is the awk built-in variable for number of fields. Using the `$NF` means to use the contents of that field.

*However*, you could shorten this (and eliminate `grep`) by just having `awk` search for the string:

```
 smartctl -A /dev/sda | awk '/Power_On_Hours/ {print $NF}'
```

Comment: That works perfect. So my command is: smartctl -A /dev/sda | grep Power_On_Hours | awk '{print $NF}'

Comment: Piping grep into awk is usually not required.

Comment: @Levon Nope, I just posted that a hair before you edited yours. It works perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I needed to grep the attributes of smartctl because it posts 15 other lines of data. So this was the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

### two `grep`s piped

```
smartctl -A /dev/sda | grep Power_On_Hours | grep -o '[0-9]+$'
```

The second `grep` will print only the matching part. Sometimes, three or more `grep`s will be needed to isolate what you are looking for. I use this for quick-and-dirty jobs.

Comment: +1 for the quick'n'dirty way of using an easier to dominate tool. (I also pipe a handful of greps quite often)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here is a zsh function that retrieves a named attribute from smartctl output using sed(1):

```
function get_smart_attrib() {
    local attrib="$1"
    local disk="$2"
    smartctl --attributes -f brief "$disk" \
        | sed -rn "/ $attrib /"'s/.{61}//p'
}
```

Only the declaration itself is zsh specific, the function body should work in most bourne-like shells.

It's also possible to do it in pure shell, with a while read loop, approximately like this (untested) ($myattr is set to the name of the attribute we're looking for):

```
smartctl -A -f brief /dev/sda | while read foo attrname foo foo foo foo foo value; do
    [[ "$attrname" = "$myattr" ]] && echo $value && break
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is clearly the right tool for this, but you can also do:

```
smartctl -A /dev/sda | grep Power_On_Hours | tr -s \  \\t | cut -f 10
```

(note the 2 spaces between the backslashes, or you might prefer `tr -s ' ' '\t'`)
The two most common tools for selecting a particular column from text are `cut` and `awk`, and you should be familiar with both.  `cut` is more finicky about whitespace than `awk`, and the purpose of the `tr` in the above pipeline is to cleanup the whitespace for `cut`.  `awk` is nice in that you can reference the last column as `$NF`, but with `cut` you need to count.